# Variable set value in runnable()

Tags: java, android, runnable

Im having a problem where I cant set the value for a variable inside a runnable(). I declare the variable idPeople, and then set the value in the following code

```
public void searchPeople(){
    final String help = etCast.getText().toString();

    request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/person?query=" + help + "&api_key=66183feb7d9585664541910fce65bde5")
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
            final String myResponse = response.body().string(); //string da resposta do site

            DiscoverActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(myResponse);
                        JSONArray results = json.getJSONArray("results"); //procura parametro results
                        idPeople = results.getJSONObject(0).getString("id");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

but the value sticks with null. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is 'idPeople' defined?

Comment: Its defined in MainActivity

Comment: There is not enough information here for the question to be answered definitively.  If I had to guess, I'd guess that it's because the JSON value is null or it's throwing an exception.  You should confirm that the JSON is correct and that exception is not being thrown.  If that doesn't solve the problem, you need to post the JSON data and more of the relevant code (for instance, the part where `idPeople` is defined, as David notes above).